F# discriminated unions simple use raises AOT and trimming warnings on publish
F#, .NET 8 console app with DUs generates AOT & trimming warnings even for simple usage.
I am creating an F#, .NET 8 (SDK 8.0.302) console app and publish as a single file with AOT, trimming. I defined a discriminated union and used it in few trivial functions. But this raises AOT and trimming warnings when I run dotnet publish command. Is this expected or am I missing something obvious? I am running:
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained true -p:PublishAot=true -p:PublishTrimmed=true -o ./publish

And the code is:
type AnyDU = X | Y

let f1 () = let unrelated = System.DateTime.Now in ()
let f2 () = let works = X in ()
let f3 () = let works = X in match works with | X -> 0 | _ -> 1
let f4 () = let unrelated = System.DateTime.Now in let fails = X in ()
let f5 () = let fails = X in if fails = X then 1 else 0

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    f1 () |> ignore // no warnings. unrelated.
    f2 () |> ignore // no warnings.
    f3 () |> ignore // no warnings.
    f4 () |> ignore // IL3053 and IL2104 warnings.
    f5 () |> ignore // IL3053 and IL2104 warnings.
    0

The fsproj file has following settings:
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsAotCompatible>true</IsAotCompatible>
    <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>

When I added <TrimmerSingleWarn>false</TrimmerSingleWarn> to fsproj, I got around 50 warnings mostly related to reflection and print formatting with warning codes: IL2055, IL2060, IL2067, IL2070, IL2072, IL2075, IL2080, IL3050.
Also, adding [<Struct>] attribute to the DU didn't help.
The example code is simplified. My real DU structure and usage is fairly complex. So enums instead of DUs is not an option.

It seems like an issue which should be reported @github. For example similar one involving similar compile errors was fixed in the latest SDK (8.0.302) but your problem reproduces for me with it on Ubuntu (have not checked the VS). P.S. on the side note - it seems that you should not use PublishReadyToRun in your command since you are using AOT.

Thanks for suggestions @GuruStron. I removed PublishReadyToRun. Tested with latest SDK 8.0.302. Discussion #17323 started on GitHub and an issue #17324 was created.
